# How to start ActivityMain from Phonegap's html file

Tags: android, cordova, android-activity, program-entry-point

This is my js function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function callNewActivity() {
            window.plugins.StartBarcodeReader.gecis();                   
            }
</script>
```

This is my StartBarcodeReader.java file

```
package com.blogspot.ehamutcu.barcodereader;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
public class StartBarcodeReader extends ActionBarActivity {
    public void gecis(){
                Intent i = new Intent(this,BarcodeReader.class);
                startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

I want to start new main activity from phonegap's index.html file

For example, One click button on the index.html than start new activity.

My english is bad :-( , please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code access the android code from cordova/phonegap's index.html.What ever you write in the input field on index.html it will then pass to the android code and came back to the index.html

```
public class AlertBack extends CordovaPlugin  {
@Override
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args,
        CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
    if (action.equals("alertBack")) {
       <!-- Here you should write your intent-->        
         Context context = this.cordova.getActivity(); //getting context
           Intent intent = new Intent(context,Yourclass.class); //mention your activity in manifest
            context.startActivity(intent);//start activity
       <!-- Intent end -->
         Toast.makeText(cordova.getActivity(), "Using Toast You Entered "+
         args.getString(0), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        callbackContext.success("Returning from native You Entered "
                + args.getString(0));
        return true;
    }
    return false; // Returning false results in a "MethodNotFound" error.
}

}
```

I am uploading a working example.You can download and test it.[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tkggbpw5zwj39jd/android.zip?dl=0).If you still face any troubles.Feel free to comment :)