# To code css using android native language

Tags: android, html, css

Actually i want to design my app through css and html and want to code that css generated elements throgh android code.
Like suppose i have created a button in css.Can i use my android native language to code that button?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25456222/how-to-start-activitymain-from-phonegaps-html-file/25457326#25457326

Answer (score 1):

Officialy, java is the development language for android. So, if we are being really strict, you should use whatever tools java and the android sdk give you to create and style your elements (you can read about it [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)). But of course, there's always more than one way of doing stuff, and thanks to the Adobe overlords, you might just have what you are asking for.

[Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) is a highly powerful opensource framework that allows you to code you entire app using HTML, CSS and JavaScript. Once you are done coding, phonegap does its magic and generates the app for you, so you don't need to touch a single line of java code.

So, basically, I don't think there's a way of using CSS in pure native android code (if there is, please feel free to share). But if you really want to use it, Phonegap is the way to go (I've used it before, it's cool)

Comment: Thanks at leat i have head start...actually i am new at this era of android development.If it is possible can u please give ur small time to me.How can i contact u..ur help would be most appreciable..thanks in advance..

Comment: You can e-mail me anytime. You can find it in my contact information